# symantec altiris - how to deploy

Tags: deployment, documentation, sccm, symantec, altiris

I am curious about the product. ( symantec - altiris ) 
I know that this product has a deployment function for software or OS upgrade.
I would like to know more about OS upgrade. 
For example, the same behavior as uploading a version on Windows 10.
I want to know exactly what follows.

1) When upgrade, I want to know how to deploy it and how to deploy it.
(For example, in SCCM, pxe start distribution, media distribution, etc.)

2) Preparations before deployment

I went to the Symantec homepage and looked at the documentation, but it seemed to lack a description of how it was deployed. (Maybe I did not find it.)

I would like you to leave a link or let me know a document that explains how to deploy.
( It is better if the data can be compared with SCCM. )

Thank you ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://www.symantec.com/products/deployment-solution).

From experience, I would definitely advise sticking with SCCM.